# save all the effect of a webpage forever

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql

Suppose i have a webpage having a button, and when i press the button it will create another button bellow that.Now i want to save the effect, that means when i will open the webpage again it will direct show the button bellow the button.
How can i store this effect in data base or in some other way?

Comment: You can use HTML5 localstorage.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to ask is "how can i do persistence"?
You can do persistence by a number of different methods , here are a few :

- saving on a file
- saving on a database
- HTML5 local storage
- cookies

For your scenario the best fit would be to use a cookie with javascript.
Here some JS code to set a cookie and to check a cookie:

```
    function setBtnCookie() {
        var showButton=getCookie("showButton");
        if (showButton=="") {
            setCookie("showButton", "true", 365);
        }
    }

    function checkCookie() {
        var showButton=getCookie("showButton");
        if (showButton=="") {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i store these html effects in database?

Comment: For your scenario ignore the overhead of a database and simply use a cookie with javascript.

Comment: For this scenario cookie is fine.